# cocos2d-x v 2.0 and Linux

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I'm newbie in mobile development.[cocos2d-x Tutorials](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Tutorials) says:

> But please note that linux port is only exist on cocos2d-x v1.x
>   versions, we remove this port in v2.0

Does it means that I can not set up development environment on Linux box to target app for example for Android or it means that I can set up development environment on Linux box, but can can not target app for Linux.

Update: link updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand it as: you can develop on Linux and deploy to Android, but you can't build native Linux apps with cocos2d-x 2.0.

I'm assuming this because they're talking about "port", which usually refers to the engine itself and not the development environment. Also the cocos2d-x 2.0 repository still includes many of the Linux files, including those necessary to build the sample project.

No guarantees though, that's just how I understand it after checking their wiki and github repo.

Comment: Thanks. Assume you understand it correctly, since I'm new to this :)

Comment: I've updated the link, it's under "Setting up the Develop Environment" section. Do you still stick with your answer?